# socket.getfqdn() and socket.gethostname() are giving Different IP addresses when using socket.gethostname

Tags: python, sockets

I am running a Virtual Machine which gives the following values and when the code is run (by doing some action on the website)

```
socket.getfqdn()
x-vps-01.abc.it

socket.gethostname()
x-vps-01

socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
216.185.103.35

socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
78.47.171.19
```

Please note that, when I log into the terminal and run the above, I always get
**78.47.171.19**

Comment: Describe your network setup, host and VM interfaces/IPs, and how you hook up into DNS.

Answer (score 13):

I tried what you did on a Linux box.  Maybe you should state what OS and network situation you are running on.

Using `strace` I found that `socket.getfqdn()` is using information provided in the file `/etc/hosts` while `socket.gethostname()` only prints data from the result of the system call `uname()`; basically you could say the one asks the network module while the other asks the kernel.  Both have an answer to your question but they do not necessarily match because they have different views on that matter.

Calling `socket.gethostbyname()` also queries the network module (searches the contents of the file `/etc/hosts` for a match in my case).  Giving the answer of the kernel to the network function isn't really what you should do.  In most cases this will work nevertheless.  You found a spot in which it produced strange results.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this issue is caused by Python bug specific to MacOS, the one that I mention at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143006/99834

Good news: there is a workaround you can run on your machine.