# Airflow signals SIGTERM to subprocesses unexpectedly

Tags: python, airflow

I am using the PythonOperator to call a function that parallelizes data engineering process as an Airflow task. This is done simply by wrapping a simple function with a callable wrapper function called by Airflow.

```
def wrapper(ds, **kwargs):
    process_data()
```

process_data achieves parallelization using the multiprocessing module that spawns subprocesses. When I run process_data all by itself from jupyter notebook, it runs to the end with no problem. However when I run it using Airflow, the task fails and the log for the task shows something like this.

```
[2019-01-22 17:16:46,966] {models.py:1610} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2019-01-22 17:16:46,969] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - Process ForkPoolWorker-129:

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,973] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - Traceback (most recent call last):

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,973] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING -   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,973] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING -   File "/home/airflow/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1612, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,973] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,993] {models.py:1610} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2019-01-22 17:16:46,996] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - Process ForkPoolWorker-133:

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,999] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - Traceback (most recent call last):

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,999] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING -   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,999] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING -   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,999] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING -   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,999] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING -   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 343, in get
    res = self._reader.recv_bytes()

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,999] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING -   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 99, in __exit__
    return self._semlock.__exit__(*args)

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,999] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING -   File "/home/airflow/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1612, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")

[2019-01-22 17:16:46,999] {logging_mixin.py:95} WARNING - airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal

[2019-01-22 17:16:47,086] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - file parsing and processing 256.07

[2019-01-22 17:17:12,938] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - combining and sorting 25.85
```

I am not quite sure why the task receives SIGTERM. My guess is that some higher level process is sending those to the subprocesses. What should I do to debug this issue?

Just noticed that towards the end of the log for the task, it clearly states that

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
[2019-01-22 12:31:39,196] {models.py:1764} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I followed the answer [here](https://www.cnblogs.com/braveym/p/12516513.html).
The idea is the same: Not letting Airflow close threads too early:

`export AIRFLOW__CORE__KILLED_TASK_CLEANUP_TIME=604800` did the trick.

Comment: Can someone explain the purpose of this parameter? i don't fully understand airflow's comments ```# When a task is killed forcefully, this is the amount of time in seconds that it has to cleanup after it is sent a SIGTERM, before it is SIGKILLED```.  Why is our task killed forcefully? Also, increasing from the default 60 seconds to 604800 seconds (7 days) seems dramatic. Any downside of this change? Thanks!

Comment: The task is killed forcefully because the airflow does not think the thread jobs are still running and think the main thread is finished. This solution is a workaround to make the airflow wait more before all threads finished. I tried the join solution, that should make the main thread wait on all thread jobs, but it does not work for me. In terms of time, this does not pose any problems in my case.

Comment: Oh I see. But how did you try the join solution? Did you dig into Airflow's source code and make changes there?

Comment: @Zach, Did you find any explanation for config killed_task_cleanup_time=xxxx, doc says something else.

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay i didn't change the config of killed_task_cleanup_time. i stopped following this thread after i upgraded to airflow 2.0.1.

Comment: This is working intermittently for me on airflow 2.0.1. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

This might help if you use a Mac (Not sure if on all versions though. Right now it is MacOS 12.1, Monterey, Python 3.8).

I tried some of the solutions above, to no avail. Then I noticed in the log for the failed task that I was getting the warning:

- WARNING - The recorded hostname
  1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa
  does not match this instance's hostname grad_mac

Then immediately afterwards the SIGTERM signal being sent by the scheduler:

- INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 70482

In the airflow.cfg, the python function **socket.getfqdn** is used by default to infer the hostname (look for line **hostname_callable = socket.getfqdn**).
I did some digging ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309560/socket-getfqdn-and-socket-gethostname-are-giving-different-ip-addresses-when)), and turns out this function behaves somewhat differently in Mac.

I replaced the line to use gethostname (**hostname_callable = socket.gethostname**), restarted the scheduler, et voilá !

In retrospect, the scheduler was trying to contact the task to check its health state (as it's what a well behaved scheduler usually does), but could not contact it with the originally inferred hostname. It would therefore assume unhealthy state, and send the kill signal...

Answer (score 1):

I too had similar issue when I was running Python multithreaded code. I was able to resolve the same by joining threads. Airflow then waits till all thread gets executed before sending SIGTERM.

```
threads = []   #array for threads

 t = Thread(...)
 threads.append(t) #add all threads

 # Start all threads
 for x in threads:
     x.start()

 # Wait for all of them to finish
 for x in threads:
     x.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

DAGs that run longer or have more than 10-12 tasks (that may run long) seem to have a higher probability of getting SIGTERM.

PROBABLE SOLUTIONS:
`schedule_after_task_execution to False`
If True, Task supervisor process runs a "mini scheduler". However, after marking it as success, it will call _run_mini_scheduler_on_child_tasks. And while local_task_job.py will detect the task as success and not running, it will terminate the process which might be still executing under _run_mini_scheduler_on_child_tasks.

The problem may also be because the scheduler health check threshold which is set to be smaller than the scheduler heartbeat interval.
The default  `scheduler_health_check_threshold` was 30 seconds and `scheduler_heartbeat_sec` was 60 seconds. During the check for orphaned tasks, the scheduler heartbeat was determined to be older than 30 seconds, which makes sense, because it was only heartbeating every 60 seconds. Thus the scheduler was inferred to be unhealthy and was therefore maybe terminated.

The logs in my case shows that the SIGTERM is associated with tasks being considered as orphaned.

As the  the timestamps coincide closely with the SIGTERM received by the task. It seems that since the SchedulerJob was marked as failed, then the TaskInstance running the actual task was considered an orphan, and thus marked for termination. I changes these values as
`scheduler_heartbeat_sec` = 60
`scheduler_health_check_threshold` = 120 (twice that of `scheduler_heartbeat_sec`)
Some explanations blamed  metadata database being used as 100% cpu while running dags with multiple tasks in parallel, such as the example used in my case.
Increasing the database may solve the issue, but instead increasing the `job_heartbeat_sec`   and the other three configurations actually solved the problem .
`job_heartbeat_sec   = 60` (roughly based on the time almost taken by the task

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is way overdue but what solved my issue was increasing the `dagrun_timeout` parameter. You should check if your execution fits the window.

Comment: Note that this is for the DAG and not for a specific task within a dag that is throwing the SIGTERM.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after upgrading from Airflow v`1.10.15` to v`2.2.5` and was seeing the error in long-running DAGs having a fairly high number of tasks.

Apparently, the `dagrun_timeout` in `airflow.models.DAG` was not respected in earlier Airflow versions so I noticed that the DAGs I was trying to migrate to the new Airflow instance were running for much longer than the specified `dagrun_timeout`.

---

The solution for me was to increase the `dagrun_timeout` (e.g. `dagrun_timeout=datetime.timedelta(minutes=120)`).

Note that this variable is effective only for scheduled tasks (in other words with DAGs with a specified `schedule_interval`).